# How to insert null value to image column in SQL Server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been trying to figure out how to save image into database with both null and image values. For my code it saves the image but if the image is missing it does not save a null value.

```
public string STDNAME { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
DateTime Date1 = DateTime.Now;
```

This the code that I used to save the data

```
public string imagepath { get; set; }

public bool Insert(StudentC c)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);

    try
    {
        byte[] imageBT = null;

        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.Image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageBT = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
        string sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (STDNAME,imagepath,Image,Date) VALUES (@STDNAME,@imagepath,@Image,@Date)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STDNAME", c.STDNAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagepath", c.imagepath);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", imageBT);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date1);

        conn.Open();

        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nMessage ---\n{0}", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

This code is for browsing the image

```
//browse image
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
    f.Filter = "All Files|*.*|JPEGs|*.jpg|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif";
    f.FilterIndex = 2;

    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(f.FileName);
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        textBox7.Text = f.SafeFileName.ToString();
        string picPath = f.FileName.ToString();
        textBox7.Text = picPath;
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picPath;
    }
}
```

This is the code to supplies the values to store

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c.STDNAME = textBox2.Text;

    c.Image = textBox7.Text;
    c.imagepath = textBox7.Text;

    bool success = c.Insert(c);

    if (success == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved");
        //Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        //    label4.Text = "Data Has not been saved";
        MessageBox.Show("Data has not been saved");
    }
}
```

Comment: _if the image is missing it does not save a null value_ so what does it save? And which part of all this code tells the DB to store a null value?

Comment: Also, to set a value as null in sql server you must pass DBNull.Value as your parameter.

Comment: What I've done in the past is leave the field that you want NULL out of the INSERT SQL. I know this can be a pain, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

For adding adding **null** to the **image** column, make sure you specify the type (e.g. VarBinary) as the example below. In addition, make sure the **image** column accepts **null**.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Moreover, the following approach may lead to the exception further below:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", DBNull.Value);
```

**--- Exception ---**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Comment: Could you provide more details (which approach did you use? exception? scenario?)?

Answer (score -1):

**Very Simple Solution

**C# Text**

```
query = "insert into Customer (CustomerCode,LdegerCode,CustomerPicture) values ('0001','9999',NULL)"
```

**Sql query Text**

```
insert into Customer (CustomerCode,LdegerCode,CustomerPicture) values ('0001','9999',NULL)
```

*if You use DBNull.Value its save Empty String in Column*